# is possible use setId() for id in doctrine entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to set id manual I write this code in my Test entity:

can I use setId() for entities like my code?

My code is here:

```
 /**
 * Test
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Set id
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

   // other methods
}
```

is this correct way to set id?
if not what is the correct and standard way?

Comment: Why you want to set id manually?

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق i want to get user information from telegram bot and set user id to id

Comment: I think it's better to add another attribut for telegram id

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق yes i do this - thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine expects the primary key of your entity to be immutable (non-changeable) **after the entity is persisted/flushed** to the database (or fetched from DB).

The code you wrote is perfectly correct in terms of PHP but will most likely break doctrine functionality if you ever use `setId()`.

If you are interested in the internals, look up "Doctrine identity maps"

Answer (score 8):

You can use your own primary key, telling to Doctrine not to generate value ...

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_generatedvalue

```
/**
 * Test
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Set id
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
```

Don't forget setId before persist!

Comment: Don't forget to clear the cache after changing the generated Value strategy and It works Fine I tested it right now.